# Coreplot 1.5.x arm64 - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: ios8, core-plot

Trying to compile using libCorePlot for arm64.  I copied the instructions from here [Using Core Plot 2 in an Xcode 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491842/using-core-plot-2-in-an-xcode-5-project)

```
lipo libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a -info
Architectures in the fat file: libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64


Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_vDSP_minvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
  "_vDSP_maxvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in later Core Plot releases. Release 1.5.1 has been out since March 2014.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Eric, I was reading another post similar to my problem and they had the link to the "latest".  but still have a new problem above.  THANK YOU

Comment: From `lipo -info`: "Architectures in the fat file: ~/CorePlot_1.5.1/Binaries/iOS/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64". It includes 64-bit code for both the device and simulator. Try a clean build.

Comment: Thanks again Eric, I do not have a binaries directory.  I used this URL https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot  I am guessing should have used something else?

Comment: Did you follow the guidelines for setting up your project in the [wiki](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Using-Core-Plot-in-an-Application#ios-application)?

Comment: Eric, The directories named BINARIES and COREPLOTHEADERS are NOT in the ZIP file. The instructions call for copying those which is what I did before with the previous version. Until arm64 came along all was great!

Comment: Eric, I found several other references to making this work and realize there must be something messed up un the scripts that run in the universal compile. I tried several of the ideas and finally did get a compile and found the coreplotheaders but now I get different errors about things missing,

Comment: I updated the above with the latest errors.  Now it doesnt work no matter if I use arm64 or not.

Comment: The vDSP errors mean you need to link the Accelerate framework into your app.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I will be testing this on Monday. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Eric when I tried to submit and validate at apple I got warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current archs = "arm64").  I dont know why but it wasnt doing this before I got the updated CorePlot.   Do you have any idea? I have a post on here about this one subject but no one has replied yet, hopefully you will know

Comment: Core Plot releases 1.5.1 and later include both 32- and 64-bit binaries in the static library. If you're building from source, make sure you get all architectures. Use the "Universal Library" build target if you're making your own standalone library to include in your app.

Comment: Yes, there are. The release download is: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases/download/release_1.5.1/CorePlot_1.5.1.zip. The iOS static library is in /Binaries/iOS.

Comment: Wish I had seen this before.  The zip I got from Github was named core-plot-master.zip  ==  Thank you --- I still have the same error so I guess its nothing to do with coreplot.  I posted a question and no one has answered, but I did show the setup on this. Eric would you mind looking and see if you see anything I did wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096072/warning-all-apps-should-include-an-armv7-architecture-current-archs-arm64

Comment: So how did you manage to build for arm64? Mine doesn't work though lipo says it would contain all arm64-stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For users still experiencing this after downloading the latest release, simply link the

> Accelerate.framework

to your app. The latest 2.2+ static library releases will now work properly.

[image]