# warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current archs = "arm64")

Tags: ios8, xcode6

warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current archs = "arm64").

I have read other posts with earlier versions of XCode and none of those examples helped fix this.  Its seems no matter what I put in the settings, as you see below, helps.  I still get the same error.

The project and the target settings look the same.  I have tried adding armv7s and that doesnt help.

I dont know why the error says current archs - arm64.  Doesnt it see everything else?

[image: Settings for Project and Target]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the order in which the architectures are in makes a difference. 
If they are not exactly in the order armv7 armv7s arm64   then it doesn't work.

Below is a screen shot of what works.

[image: Working Config]