# Dtrace Error after building libCorePlot-cocoaTouch project for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I was following this answer ([Using Core Plot 2 in an Xcode 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23900552)) to solve my problem of building a project at Xcode 6 - iOS 8 , but i got new strange error. Here is image of error and description.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling the error I found out the solution :

1. Delete CPTBoarderLayerd.d
2. Clean project
3. Add CPTBoarderLayerd.d
4. Make "Build Valid Architecture Only" Yes [image]