# iOS CorePlot how to install

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to use CorePlot in one of my iOS projects, but even after following the instructions and looking around online, I haven't managed to correctly install the framework. I feel like the documentation has not evolved and no longer describes the correct way to install the framework.

I followed [these instructions](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications). But some things do not make sense to me, either because they are no longer current or because I don't understand.

For instance, when I am told to add the library to the "Link binaries with binary" section, the Core Plot library is highlighted in red. Then when I am told to edit the Header Search Paths, I don't understand what to do because the .xcodeproj file I dragged into my project does not have a "framework" folder.

Could anyone please give up-to-date, noob-friendly instructions?

Thank you.

Edit: I tried to install according to the instructions below (manual installation) and I am now getting three errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_vDSP_maxvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
  "_vDSP_minvD", referenced from:
      -[CPTPlot plotRangeForField:] in libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a(CPTPlot.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Probably, this will help you : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Comment: The Core Plot repository moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot). The updated installation instructions are on the [wiki](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Using-Core-Plot-in-an-Application).

Comment: I read them, I just can't manage to make it work because I am just not used to installing these things, I suppose...

Comment: I have posted the correct solution for the problem you were facing and a link with more details about the problem please check and verify my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Foundry's answer is great if you use Cocoapods, but I'll will provide you a step-by-step guide to do it manually :

1. Create a folder named `Workspace`, and create a new "testCoreplot" project in it from within Xcode.
2. Download CorePlot, and copy the "Source/framework" folder into your workspace folder. Rename it "CoreplotFramework" in order to avoid issues if you add others frameworks this way later.

You should have this :

[image]

3. Launch your testCoreplot project, and drag the file "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj" from the finder in it.
4. Selet the testCoreplot target, go to 'Build Phases" tab, and add "CorePlot-CocoaTouch" in "target dependencies" section and "libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a" in "Link Binary With Libraries" section. Add the `Accelerate` framework too for release 2.0.

[image]

5. Go to "Build settings" tab, look for "Header search paths" and add  `$(SRCROOT)/../CoreplotFramework` . Be sure you select `recursive` .

[image]

6. Still in this "build settings" tab, add the `-ObjC` flag

[image]

7. Go to ViewController.m and add

   ```
   #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
   ```
8. Compile, everything should be right !

Comment: Thank you very much for your very thorough reply.

I did everything you said. Just to make sure, the folder I copied into my workspace was the "framework" folder, it contains the header files, the cocoa XCode Project and all the .h and .m files within the "Source" subfolder.

I get three errors related to the Header Search Paths. Please see my question for details.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You copied the right folder, don't worry about that ;) My example is made for the 1.5.1 release, but using the 2.0 release i got the same errors. According to https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/76, you have to add the Accelerate framework, and it will compile fine. You can do following my example, step 4, 'link binary with libraries', and search for 'Accelerate'

Comment: Hi, I still get a ```'Core-Plot-CocoaTouch.h" file not found``` when I try to import the header file. I notice that my ```libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a``` is highlighted red

Comment: Nevermind, not sure what changed, but it's working. Thanks for the great answer

Comment: @Momo Im having same problem! :-\

Answer (score 4):

Core Plot provides a [podspec](http://cocoapods.org/?q=corePlot), so you can use [cocoapods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/) as your library manager which should make installing and updating much simpler

1. [Install cocoapods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) on your system
2. Add a text file to your project called `Podfile`
3. In the Podfile add the line `pod 'CorePlot', '~> 1.5'`
4. In the terminal, cd to your project directory and run `pod install`

Cocoapods will generate a `xcworkspace` file, which you should use for launching your project (the `.xcodeproj` file will not include the pod libraries)

Answer (score 0):

@foundry's answer is what worked best for me. All other things I tried triggered lots of weird issues.

This is how I did it:
At the root of the directory project, create a plain text file named `Podfile` (no txt extension), then add the following to it:

`target 'App Name' do
    pod 'CorePlot', '~> 2.2'
end`

with `App Name` being your App name, i.e. `MyApp.xcodeproj`, then just use `MyApp`.

Then, from your terminal, run `pod init`, followed by `pod install`. After this, from Finder, don't run the original `MyApp.xcodeproj` anymore, but the newly created `MyApp.xcworkspace`.

It just worked like a charm...