# issue with using Core Plot in XCode6.1

Tags: ios8, core-plot, xcode6.1

I followed each step successfully from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491842/using-core-plot-2-in-an-xcode-5-project). I am able to import

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

But When I Build My Project I get linker Error.How I can resolve this error.

[Here](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dalvik/folders/Jing/media/68813714-5bd3-4fb3-b4c0-70087975ae46/00000044.png) is the screenshot of the error that i am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those missing symbols are from the Accelerate framework. Recent Core Plot builds require your app to link that framework, too.

Comment: Thnx a lot Eric. When i added Accelerate framework all the errors resolved. :)